# How to make Scrapy show user agent per download request in log?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler, user-agent

I am learning [Scrapy](http://scrapy.org/), a web crawling framework.

I know I can set `USER_AGENT` in `settings.py` file of the Scrapy project. When I run the Scrapy, I can see the `USER_AGENT`'s value in `INFO` logs.
This `USER_AGENT` gets set in every download request to the server I want to crawl.

But I am using multiple `USER_AGENT` **randomly** with the help of [this solution](http://tangww.com/2013/06/UsingRandomAgent/). I guess this randomly chosen `USER_AGENT` would be working. I want to confirm it. So, how I can make Scrapy **shows** `USER_AGENT` per download request so I can see the value of `USER_AGENT` in the logs?

Answer (score 30):

Just FYI.

I've implemented a simple [`RandomUserAgentMiddleware` middleware](https://github.com/alecxe/scrapy-fake-useragent) based on [`fake-useragent`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/fake-useragent).

Thanks to `fake-useragent`, you don't need to configure the list of User-Agents - it picks them up [based on browser usage statistics](http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_stats.asp) from a [real-world database](http://useragentstring.com).

Comment: But why didn't add it to PyPI?

Comment: @theotheo done, please see https://pypi.python.org/pypi/scrapy-fake-useragent. Thanks for the idea.

Comment: @alecxe I am using fake-useragent in my project but it is throwing               " raise FakeUserAgentError('Error occurred during getting browser')  # noqa
FakeUserAgentError: Error occurred during getting browser"  Error.

Comment: @daved are you still having this problem? From time to time, there are temporary issues related to connecting to the source of real world user agents..

Comment: @alecxe  yes, this problem was not there 2 weeks ago. Can I do anything about it? is there any way to avoid it? Thanks.

Comment: I found that the error occurs while using the internet explorer browser: `from fake_useragent import UserAgent
ua = UserAgent()
ua.ie #error
ua.msie #error
ua['Internet Explorer'] #error` other browsers are working..

Comment: @daved interesting! Looks like [this issue](https://github.com/hellysmile/fake-useragent/issues/41) is exactly about your problem.

Comment: @alecxe I slightly changed your scrapy_fake_agent middlewear to handle this exception. What I did is whenever exception occurred I am calling get random browser to download recursively untill the exception does not occur - until internet explorer is not getting called. This way it is skipping the internet explorer browser which is throwing the exception. And thanks for your reply and your software module.

Comment: it was working perfect for me, before i implement `scrapy-splash` in my requests. It seems like splash doesn't care about random user agent middleware inside scrapy ? Anyone can help on it ?

Answer (score 20):

You can see it by using this:

```
def parse(self, response):
    print response.request.headers['User-Agent']
```

You can use `scrapy-fake-useragent` python library. It works perfectly and it chooses user agent based on world usage statistic. But be careful, check if it's already working perfectly using above code since you might do some mistake when applying it. Read the instruction carefully.

Answer (score 11):

You can add logging to [solution](http://tangww.com/2013/06/UsingRandomAgent/) you're using:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
#-*-coding:utf-8-*-
import random

from scrapy import log
from scrapy.contrib.downloadermiddleware.useragent import UserAgentMiddleware

class RotateUserAgentMiddleware(UserAgentMiddleware):
    def __init__(self, user_agent=''):
        self.user_agent = user_agent

    def process_request(self, request, spider):
        ua = random.choice(self.user_agent_list)
        if ua:
            request.headers.setdefault('User-Agent', ua)

            # Add desired logging message here.
            spider.log(
                u'User-Agent: {} {}'.format(request.headers.get('User-Agent'), request),
                level=log.DEBUG
            )


    #the default user_agent_list composes chrome,IE,firefox,Mozilla,opera,netscape
    #for more user agent strings,you can find it in http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/useragentstring.php
    user_agent_list = [
        "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/22.0.1207.1 Safari/537.1",
        "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; CrOS i686 2268.111.0) AppleWebKit/536.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/20.0.1132.57 Safari/536.11",
        "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/536.6 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/20.0.1092.0 Safari/536.6",
    ]
```

Comment: Sorry, how can I use this class inside the spider for affectively rotate ua?

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT:** I came here because I was looking for the functionality to change the user agent.

Based to alecxe's RandomUserAgent, this is what I use to set the user agent only once per crawl and only from a predefined list (works for me with scrapy v. 0.24 & 0.25):

```
    """
    Choose a user agent from the settings but do it only once per crawl.
    """
    import random
    import scrapy

    SETTINGS = scrapy.utils.project.get_project_settings()


    class RandomUserAgentMiddleware(object):
        def __init__(self):
            super(RandomUserAgentMiddleware, self).__init__()
            self.fixedUserAgent = random.choice(SETTINGS.get('USER_AGENTS'))
            scrapy.log.msg('User Agent for this crawl is: {}'.
                           format(self.fixedUserAgent))

        def process_start_requests(self, start_requests, spider):
            for r in start_requests:
                r.headers.setdefault('User-Agent', self.fixedUserAgent)
                yield r
```

**The actual answer to your question is: Check for the UA by using a local webserver and see check the logs (e.g. /var/log/apache2/access.log on *NIX).**